# launching app when dial a number in android

Tags: android

Here am performing a task where when am dial a specific number like 123 by dial-er then open a new activity and if dial another number then it will be calling . On dial 123 ask for calling or open app. So please provide me the information about this that how could i perform this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

you need to create a broadcast receiver. in manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".yourReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In code

```
    public class yourReceiverextends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //startyour activity
        }
    }
```

dont forget to use permission

```
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i can't perform this. So you can send me a small sample for this. That will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @Stine pike i required same thing but on specific number dial i want to open my application.

Comment: @Pankaj use a broadcastreceiver to receive the call broadcast. and in onreceive launch your launcher activity.

Comment: @AndroidHelp what is the problem you are facing? if you did everything welll the above code should work

Answer (score 0):

this code is true, but in AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter android:priority="10">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

then in CallReceiver so extends BroadcastReceive:

```
public class PhoneCallReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "VahidTAG";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "in Calling");
}
```